# 404s "tracker" for Mac OS X

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for OS X software that can help me track 404 errors on my site.

Comment: Do you mean broken links?

Comment: yes, 404 i.e. broken links

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Server Fault or Super User?

Comment: It's a request for software that runs on a Mac. It's on topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you using to watch the stats on your website? Most stats packages that read the logs will give you a 404 report (eg. [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), [Summary](http://summary.net/)).

If you're looking for a program to run on your Mac to check that for you; [Piltdown Link Checker](http://medinfo.ufl.edu/omi/tools/piltdown/), [Integrity](http://peacockmedia.co.uk/integrity/), [WebLight](http://www.illumit.com/weblight/) or [LinkByLink](http://www.linkbylink.net/) are all options.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track broken links, the best way to do it is checking the production/online site. I’ve used [BrokenLinkCheck](http://www.brokenlinkcheck.com/) in the past. It’s free and it delivers. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: i asked for a software not online service, but thanks anyway!

Comment: An online service *is* a form of software. You might have a reason to prefer *local* software over software running on a remote machine, but "software" and "online service" are not mutually exclusive categories.